# Requirements Engineering - What is SM diagram?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have been looking for the meaning of the term "SM diagram" for over half an hour now. Does a term such as that exist ? If so what does it stand for, where can I learn about it ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML has a State Machine Diagram. Is this what you are studying?

[State Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram)

[Another article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine)

Comment: I hate it when people are abstract, thanks a lot that is probably what they meant by SM.